# Complex analyis, verifying harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is: Verify for each given function $u$ is harmonic (in the region where it is defined) and then find a harmonic conjugate of $u$.

$u = \mbox{Im}(e^{z^2})$

I know how to find the harmonic conjugate, but how should my proof of the function being harmonic look like? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My confusion is that I'm first supposed to prove that u is harmonic, and then find the harmonic conjugate, normally, I would like to find the harmonic conjugate, then check if they obey the laplace equation, but if I do that here, when the question is looking like this, it feels wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Let $z=x+iy$, then
$$u(x,y)=\mbox{Im}(\exp(z^2))=\mbox{Im}(\exp(x^2-y^2+2ixy))=e^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy).$$
In order to verify that it is harmonic check if the Laplacian of $u$ is identically zero
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 y}=0.$$

Note that $e^{z^2}$ is a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$ so the harmonic conjugate will be 
$$-\mbox{Re}(\exp(z^2))=-e^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy).$$

Comment: thanks for your answer Robert Z, I think I was a bit unclear in my question, but how do I prove that u is a harmonic function?

Comment: @Stratbomber  Check if the laplacian of $u$ is identically zero.

Comment: ahh, okay, thanks, dont know why I had such a hard time with this last time!